# Label border not appearing (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, border

I have created a text label (`title_label`) in Interface Builder, I have declared it in my `FirstViewController.h` file and I would now like to add a border to it. I have added the code to do this but when I run the app the border simply doesn't appear.

Here is the code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    title_label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    title_label.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This is the content of `FirstViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *title_label;

}

@end
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: viewDidLoad is the method that gets called when every GUI has been loaded. You need to do it initWithCoder as i assume you are using Storyboards.

Comment: Can u check and  conform the IBOutlet of the UILable once?

Comment: just try my answer and let me know whether it is coming or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *title_label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 150, 40)];
    title_label.text = @"Text Which Comes";
    title_label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    title_label.layer.borderWidth = 4.0;
    title_label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    [self.view addSubview:title_label];
}
```

**Imported** `QuartzCore` **framework**

Comment: This creates a new label over the existing one, not what I am looking for

Comment: I know that... if this is working then problem is with your IBConnections only. inorder to clarify i just asked you to put my code....Check your IBConnections properly

Comment: I have checked my connections properly, but since I am just getting started, how am I supposed to know what I am missing? :D

Comment: can you paste an image of your xib ?

Comment: where you had connected the label connection dude ? the image tells ki that you are not connected the label connection

Comment: But I don't know how to add a connection! :D Why isn't it enough to declare a label in IB and to use that label in the code (like in Android, for example)? :D

Comment: Naah, okay, New Referencing Outlet rite ? Just touch the buble right next to it and drag to the title and drop on the title... so you will get all the declarations made.. choose the label variable

Comment: Thanks mate :) Sorry, but iOS development until now seems much overcomplicated to me ;)

Comment: It's okay.. Have fun in iOS

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your same code, for me its working fine. I think you may forget

[image]

1.declare with `IBOutlet` and

2.connect with xib label.

Check once again